# AltGr opens menu shortcut tooltips in Matlab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, matlab

When I press `Alt Gr` / `AltGr` in Matlab, it triggers the menu bar to show the shortcut letters as tooltips on the respective buttons. This would be great if I would want to use a `Alt Gr + Hotkey` shortcut, but is quite annoying when trying to get to the much needed `{}[]` characters.

How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I disabled this behavior with the command found here:

```
com.mathworks.desktop.mnemonics.MnemonicsManagers.get.disable
```

It can be executed in the Matlab command line or put into `startup.m` for automatic execution.

This seems to be a problem appearing and discussed from time to time in the MathWorks forum. One answer I found [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54203-how-can-i-disable-toolstrip-keybindings) suggests the above.